# Passing a Bash array as arguments

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

NEW_ARGS=()

for (( i=1; i <= "$#"; i++ )) do
        if [ -f "${!i}" ]; then
                NEW_ARGS+=" $(basename ${!i})"
        else
                NEW_ARGS+=" ${!i}"
        fi
done

wine /usr/local/bin/red-063.exe ${NEW_ARGS[@]}
```

Note leading space in `NEW_ARGS+=" ${!i}"`.

If I do not do that, `${NEW_ARGS[@]}` get concatenated and passed as one argument to `wine /usr/local/bin/red-063.exe`, like:

```
redwin -t -f /home/mark/projects/learn/red_learn/a.red
...
wine /usr/local/bin/red-063.exe -t-fa.red
```

I can add those spaces, but it feels "unnatural". Is there a way to pass an array to a command in Bash just like you can pass `$*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add new elements to the array instead of concatenating everything in the first element:

```
NEW_ARGS+=("$(basename ${!i})")
NEW_ARGS+=("${i}")
```

Then pass the whole array element by element:

```
wine /usr/local/bin/red-063.exe "${NEW_ARGS[@]}"
```